# SQLite Android Disk I/O Error 10 (266) when creating Database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up a new Xamarin Forms (Android) Application from Scratch and want to implement a SQLite Database with Entity Framework Core. No matter where I let EF Core create the database I get a SQLite Disk I/O Error 10 (Extended Error Code 266).

Note: (I already created Xamarin Forms Applications with EF Core (SQLite) where the database could be created as I try it this time and no error like this occurred)

1. I tried moving all EF related code away from the UI-Thread so I can be sure that the UI-Thread isn't locking the path of the applications folder or something like that.
2. I tried different paths to create my database file.
3. Async / Non-Async database creation by ef core.
4. (I'm using DI with Autofac) I tried removing all Autofac related code and initializing the needed DatabseContext by myself.
5. I made sure that I have all the needed permissions to write to a file/read from a file in Android.

(6. I also tried to register my dependencies in different ways, to make sure Autofac or DI, in general, isn't the problem of the thrown error)

In my android MainActivity I read out the database path and pass it to my Xamarin.Forms Application like this:

```
SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());
string databasePath = Application.ApplicationContext.GetDatabasePath("target.db").AbsolutePath;
```

I also create an instance of AppSetup which is a class I use to let all needed dependencies being registered by autofac.

```
public AppSetup(string databasePath)
{
    _databasePath = databasePath;
}

public IContainer CreateContainer()
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    RegisterDependencies(containerBuilder);
    return containerBuilder.Build();
}

protected virtual void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
{
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<TargetContext>().As<ITargetContext>().WithParameter("databasePath", _databasePath).SingleInstance();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();
    containerBuilder.RegisterType<SettingsRepository>().As<ISettingsRepository>().SingleInstance();
}
```

After all of this is done, I create the database file like this in my App.xaml.cs:

```
// Register types and create container
AppContainer.Container = setup.CreateContainer();

// Begin lifetime scope of container
using var scope = AppContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope();

var context = scope.Resolve<ITargetContext>();
context.Initialize();
```

In context.Initialize() I let EF core create the database (if it isn't created already) and this is where the Exception is thrown:

```
public bool Initialize()
{
    bool result = Database.EnsureCreated();
    return result;
}
```

Note: The configuration of the DatabaseContext:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_databasePath}");

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

I expect that EF core can create the SQLite database file without any problem. I looked up for a solution for this error for several days but nothing could help me solving the error.

PS: The stacktrace I'm getting with this error:

```
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC (System.Int32 rc, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db) [0x0006d] in <99138fe6fbac4a1b964cb2ae266abca2>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open () [0x00130] in <99138fe6fbac4a1b964cb2ae266abca2>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection (System.Boolean errorsExpected) [0x00068] in <f837de81a58c413490ebba0c6077cbc0>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open (System.Boolean errorsExpected) [0x00042] in <f837de81a58c413490ebba0c6077cbc0>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists () [0x0000c] in <971e586a59454fdbaaa76f95799fac73>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated () [0x00008] in <f837de81a58c413490ebba0c6077cbc0>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated () [0x0000b] in <6f7983df5846436f8e9cb779867785c7>:0 
  at Target.ServiceLayer.TargetContext.Initialize () [0x00002] in C:\Users\Nicklas\Source\Repos\XFTarget\Target\Target\ServiceLayer\TargetContext.cs:28
```

EDIT (1): PS: I'm debugging my application on a real device, but other sample applications I created with xamarin forms + ef core can create their database successfully on this device.

Comment: Error 266 documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_read fwiw.

Comment: what is the actual path you are using?

Comment: @Shawn Yeah I saw the documentation already, but I couldn't figure out how I could resolve this error (Or why other most equal applications don't throw this type of error)

Comment: @Jason Most of the time I tried it with these two absolute pathes: 
1. "/data/user/0/com.companyname.applicationname/databases/target.db"
2. "/data/user/0/com.companyname.applicationname/files/target.db"

I also verified each time that the specified directory exists before passed the path to the application.

Comment: @Nick77, I find one article about implementing a SQLite Database with Entity Framework Core, you can take a look:https://medium.com/@yostane/data-persistence-in-xamarin-using-entity-framework-core-e3a58bdee9d1

Comment: Hey @Cherry Bu - MSFT thanks for the article, I read through it but couldn't find a difference to my approach.